# Certain WiFi connections are greyed out and not accessible

Tags: raspbian, wpa-supplicant, pi-3a+

Certain WiFi connections are greyed out and not accessible on Raspbian. I did try to modify the wpa_supplicant.conf but the changes don't seem to work. Does anybody know the correct way to add a WiFi with Radius auth

`sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` - is the file i am editing

I try to add:

```
    ssid="YOUR_NETWORK_NAME"
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
    pairwise=CCMP TKIP
    group=CCMP TKIP
    identity="YOUR_USER_NAME"
    password=hash:YOUR_PASSWORD_HASH
    phase1="peaplabel=0"
    phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
}
```

Comment: `it reverts back to the original state of the file` exactly how are you modifying that file, and exactly which file are you modifying?

Comment: @JaromandaX `sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` 
I try to add:
`network={
ssid="YOUR_NETWORK_NAME"
proto=RSN
key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
pairwise=CCMP TKIP
group=CCMP TKIP
identity="YOUR_USER_NAME"
password=hash:YOUR_PASSWORD_HASH
phase1="peaplabel=0"
phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
}`

Comment: Please don't use comments for additional information. It's unreadable. Instead [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/113050/edit) your question and add it there.

Answer (score 1):

After editing if you then

```
cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

it should still show your changes.

**As the changes go after you reboot I think you card has gone to read only mode as it's failed.**

You can test by creating a file (`touch testfile` will suffice) into the home directory and then rebooting.  You will see it with `ls` before the reboot due to the SD card changes being in the cache and as this is cleared on reboot it will not be in the directory after if the card is read only